# Ubuntu 14.04 Wifi Not Working Lenovo G570

Tags: 14.04, wireless

Hello i am new to ubuntu and wifi is not working properly.It is not showing wifi connections also.
I tried every possible solution posted on askubuntu.Need Help
Results of
lshw -c net

```
       *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: c1
   serial: 20:89:84:28:c1:b8
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp          10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c   driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.34 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:44 memory:d0500000-d053ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 08:ed:b9:0d:c9:4a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:17 memory:d0400000-d0403fff
```

lsmod gives

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 53664  8 
bnep                   18895  2 
binfmt_misc            13140  1 
wl                   6144826  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45440  1 
snd_hda_codec_conexant    47785  1 
cfg80211              409394  1 wl
snd_hda_intel          42794  6 
snd_hda_codec         164067  3               snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13272  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                85501  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         14230  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            25135  1 snd_seq_midi
uvcvideo               71309  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13048  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13170  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
intel_rapl             18301  0 
videobuf2_core         39258  1 uvcvideo
snd_seq                55383  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    13845  0 
intel_powerclamp       14239  0 
videodev              108503  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
coretemp               13195  0 
crc32_pclmul           12967  0 
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
rts5139               269330  0 
joydev                 17101  0 
serio_raw              13230  0 
shpchp                 32128  0 
lpc_ich                16864  0 
snd_timer              28584  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    60939  23  snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawm idi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
soundcore              12600  1 snd
ideapad_laptop         17872  0 
sparse_keymap          13708  1 ideapad_laptop
mac_hid                13037  0 
btusb                  27580  0 
mei_me                 18195  0 
i915                  710013  4 
bluetooth             342208  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
mei                    66737  1 mei_me
video                  18903  1 i915
drm_kms_helper         48868  1 i915
parport_pc             31981  0
```

drm                   244037  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
   i2c_algo_bit           13197  1 i915
   ppdev                  17391  0 
   lp                     13299  0 
   parport                40836  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
   psmouse                91357  0 
   atl1c                  40949  0 
   ahci                   25579  2 
  libahci                27214  1 ahci

Comment: Add the results of `lshw -c net` and `rfkill list all` to your question

Comment: Added lshw -c net and rfkill list results

Comment: Try the below syntax to reset the wifi connection "ifconfig wlan0 down"
"ifconfig wlan0 up"

Comment: ifconfig wlan0 down gives wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `uname -a` shows you are using kernel 3.16, your wireless should work after

`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`
If you are using 3.16, just add it to your question as you will need the utopic version

According to http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/ the b43 driver doesn't work with the BCM4313 card but it is time to see if it works anyhow as the bcmwl isn't working
`sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`
`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`

Reboot

Comment: uname -a result is Linux harshitpunn 3.13.0-46-generic #77-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 2 18:26:13 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: So the `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` should work then

Comment: I already executed that command but there is no change in the situation

Comment: Ok, do this and copy the terminal output `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` hopefully it will show why it doesn't work

Comment: It install the package but still problem not solved

Comment: post `dkms status`

Comment: bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 3.13.0-46-generic, i686: installed

Comment: Post results from `cat etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf`

Comment: # Warning: This file is autogenerated by bcmwl. All changes to      this file will be lost.
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

Comment: That is correct, so the issue might be `cat /etc/modules`

Comment: # /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
# Parameters can be specified after the module name.

lp
b43

Comment: `sudo modprobe -r bcma`  `sudo modprobe -r b43`    `gksudo gedit /etc/modules` and delete any line with `b43` `or `bcma` but bcma doesn't seem to be there.  Save and exit `sudo modprobe wl` `sudo depmod -a` reboot

Comment: i can see enable wifi but it shows wifi disabled under wifi networks

Comment: `rfkill list all` change and is wl loaded `lsmod | grep wl`

Comment: rfkill list all:0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
4: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: lsmod | grep wl
wl                   6144826  0 
cfg80211              409394  1 wl

Comment: Edit question to add the current results from `lshw -c net` and `lsmod`

Comment: Done kindly check

Comment: Reboot with ethernet cable unplugged as unless something very strange is going on, this card should work

Comment: Still not working